# Why doesn't rails put quotes around "NaN" when making a Postgres query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a part of my app with an error where the browser is sending up `NaN` instead of a value, resulting in a query like this:

```
Foo.create(category: 'a string', the_value: 'NaN');
```

Which results in this query:

```
INSERT INTO "foos" ("category", "the_value") VALUES ('a string', NaN);
```

Which results in this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "nan" does not exist
'a string', NaN, ...
            ^
```

All these queries succeed, and logs show the value is quoted correctly in the generated sql:

```
Foo.create(category: 'a string', the_value: '1');
Foo.create(category: 'a string', the_value: 1);
Foo.create(category: 'a string', the_value: 'a value');
Foo.create(category: 'a string', the_value: 'NaNa');
```

Why is Rails not putting quotes around 'NaN'? Some googling suggest that this string has some significance to Postgres. So maybe Rails is trying to respect the postgres semantics, but postgres would only notice if the column were a float type, something like that?

Postgres 12, rails 5.2

Comment: NaN is the special numeric ["not a number" value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-numeric.html), you can get the Ruby version by saying `x = 0.0/0`. In PostgreSQL, `'NaN'::numeric` is a thing but just raw `NaN` is not. What type is the `the_value` column?

Comment: the type of the_value is decimal

Comment: `decimal` and `numeric` are the same thing in PostgreSQL. Which version of Rails is this? I can't reproduce the problem in Rails6.

Comment: the version of rails is 5.2

Comment: I just confirmed this broken behavior with Rails 5.2, Rails 6.1 seems okay with it. My Rails6.1 app does the INSERT with a placeholder so someone else deals with the type conversion (i.e. `INSERT INTO "nonsenses" ("thing") VALUES ($1)`) my 5.2 app does the INSERT without a placeholder (i.e. `INSERT INTO "nonsenses" ("thing") VALUES (NaN)`) so Rails is doing the conversion. I'd try add some validations to ensure numericality of the column in question, if that doesn't work you can mangle those strings yourself to keep things from breaking. Reporting a Rails bug might be worthwhile too.